# WTForm hidden-token update when it expires with SocketIo

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-socketio

Im developing a app which has a form but i need the form to be usable for long periods of time because the app works in a static tablet fixed to a wall. Im using a hidden tag, so when it expires the page must be refreshed manually. Im using sockets so i thought that instead of taking off the expiring time of tokens i could send a new token through a socket when the expiry time is coming. The problem with sending a new token is how and if i should do it...

I thought a solution by sending new tokens every 30 minutes to the clients:

It starts by sending 2 tokens on rendering (instead of just the hidden tag). 
One of them (the one that is not the wtform token) uses jwt and is the result of encrypting a datetime which is the datetime when the actual hidden tag was updated (in rendering would be created on request so it would be the time of rendering). The second token is the token of the hidden tag itself.

Every 30 minutes the client-side would send a request with the jwt token to a socket handler that would check that have at least passed 30 minutes from the datetime in the token and then emit the 2 tokens (the new token of wtforms and the updated encrypted datetime to use in the next emit by the client-side) this way i prevent some client from editing the front end to send thousands of request for new tokens which i thougt could be problematic (maybe its not).

I dont think pasting the code would be of much help because i have a theorical question about working of the logic of the code more than a code itself.

My expected result is to have a working front-end form which uses a token to prevent csrf without deactivating the expiry time of the tokens.

MY QUESTIONS ARE:

is there a real necessity of using that jwt encrypted token instead of just giving a new token to every client asking for one ?

is there a better solution to the problem i have more than the one i thought ?

Comment: Maybe it is not worth the complexity of using that second token just to avoid something that isnt a problem itself. maybe i just should focus on preventing multiple request to all sockets and not make an internal solution for this

Comment: Do you really need to worry about CSRF in this case? The vulnerability is based on the attacker submitting a form to your site. With Socket.IO this isn't really possibly, since there is no way for an attacker to emit anything without first connecting. As long as you have strong authentication upon connection, any events sent afterwards can be trusted, since they are going to go through the same WebSocket connection.

Comment: Yes, i thought about it but i wasnt sure, thanks for the answer. So again SocketIo showing us how great as a protocol it is or at least to my newbie eyes its a really solid protocol that mitigates a lot of problems.